# How to programatically add/remove nodes from main graph in Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorboard seems to arbitrarily select which nodes belong to the main graph and which do not. During graph visualization I can manually add/remove the nodes but it is tedious to do it every run.

Is there a way to programmatically embed this information (which nodes belong on the main graph) during writing the graph summary?

[image: tensorboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5305) , it's not feasible at the moment.

And according to this quote :

> Thanks @lightcatcher for the suggestion. @danmane, please take a look
>   at this issue. **If it is something we will not do in the short-term
>   maybe mark it contributions welcome.** If it is something you are
>   planning to include in your plugin API anyways, please close the issue
>   to keep the backlog clear.

, and the status of the issue (`contributions:welcomed`), it's not something that is to be expected in the short term.

Comment: The issue has been migrated a few times.. but there is no progress yet
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/82